# Deleting or reposition a pointer

Tags: objective-c

I have an Model Class. When I call a the method "setter", I set some String values to the attributes of my object. After the attributes are set, the method returns the new Object which is stored in the `NSMutableArray *eintraegeSortiert`.

Now, I need a new Object. I think I have to remove the pointer and set it again. If I don't remove the pointer, all the objects stored in the mutable array will change too and I have stored the same object a 100 times in that mutable array. I have tried in multiple ways, without getting it right. What am I doing wrong? My code:

```
NSMutableArray *eintraegeSortiert = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < ([mArray count] / 11) ; i++) {
        Vertretung *vertretung = [[Vertretung alloc] init];
        [eintraegeSortiert addObject:[self setter:mArray :vertretung]];
    }
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit more, what do you mean by removing the pointer, as matt explained step-by-step, you are creating a new object each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not really understanding how the code you've written works. Let's take a look at it:

```
NSMutableArray *eintraegeSortiert = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < ([mArray count] / 11) ; i++) {
    Vertretung *vertretung = [[Vertretung alloc] init];
    [eintraegeSortiert addObject:[self setter:mArray :vertretung]];
}
```

So step by step:

```
NSMutableArray *eintraegeSortiert = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Creates a new mutable array and assigns it to `eintraegeSortiert`

```
for (int i = 0; i < ([mArray count] / 11) ; i++) {
```

We're going to loop `[mArray count] / 11` times.

```
Vertretung *vertretung = [[Vertretung alloc] init];
[eintraegeSortiert addObject:[self setter:mArray :vertretung]];
```

Now, this is creating a variable *within the current scope* called `vertretung`. You call `alloc`/`init`. That will return a pointer to a new `Vertretung` object. For example this might be at memory location `0x12345678`. Then you add that to the array.

Then we get to the end of the current scope and loop back around the for-loop. That means the variable `vertretung` goes out of scope.

Then when you loop around again, that same code runs again and again. But now the `alloc`/`init` will create an entirely new `Vertretung` object (maybe pointing to memory location `0xabcdef00` and add *that* to the array.

So no, it's not the same object being added to the array multiple times.

Not sure what's going on in `setter::` - maybe post that as well if you're still having issues.

Comment: I think you're right. I found a mistake. I've logged the memory and it isn't the same object, that is shown over and over again. I'll mark your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *eintraegeSortiert = [NSMutableArray array];
 for (int i = 0; i < ([mArray count] / 11) ; i++) {
       Vertretung *vertretung = [[Vertretung alloc] init];
       [eintraegeSortiert addObject:[self setter:mArray :vertretung]];
       [vertretung release];
       vertretung=nil;

}
```

Comment: Not if he's using ARC. And the `vertretung = nil;` is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm using ARC. I've tried this. I'm not allowed to do it like this :(